# On multiple ListPlot

Tags: plotting

Suppose that I have a following data:

```
tab = {{1,2,-3,5}, {5,-2,3,1}, {2,0,4,5}};
```

I want to make a `ListPlot` based on `tab` as follows:

1. Focusing on the first and the second column, plot (1,2), (5,-2), (2,0).
2. Focusing on the first and the third column, plot (1,-3), (5,3), (2,4).
3. Focusing on the first and the last column, plot (1,5), (5,1), (2,5).

I want to make the colors in three groups 1., 2., and 3. different.
How can I achieve this? (Of course, this is a simple example and my real data has a large number of points, but the number of column can be handled by hand.)

Comment: You can access data by 1. `tab[[All , {1, 2}]]` , 2. `tab[[All , {1, 3}]]` 3. `tab[[All , {1, -1}]]`. If you plot them all together Mathematica will assign different colors, if not use `PlotStyle`.

Comment: @BenIzd This perfectly answers my question. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Nasser The questions is already answered, but my intention was that if there are $n$ columns, then the first and the $i$-th columns for each $2\leq i \leq n$ are used. In my application, $n=6$.

Comment: [A related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66866).

Comment: @eigenvalue Your welcome. Also, remember for the last point, I use `-1`, which depends on the number of columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your data looks like this

```
data = Transpose@Join[{0.1*Range[10]},Sort/@RandomReal[1,{10,10}]];
TableForm@data
```

[image]

You can [`ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) all columns except the first against the first column, without  specifying the number of columns, like this

```
With[
    {n=Length[First@data]},
    ListLinePlot[
        Table[
            data[[All,{1,j}]]
            ,{j,2,n}
        ]
        , PlotStyle  -> Array[Hue,n,{0,0.8}]
        , PlotLegends-> Table[StringTemplate["`` vs ``"][j,1],{j,2,n}]
    ]
]
```

[image]